# Почему не распознаёт выражение в третьем операнде?

Tags: c++, mingw, тернарный-оператор

Есть простая задача по вычислению общего времени лодки в пути по течению и против. Пытаясь учесть случай,где скорость течения и лодки одинаковы при помощи тернарного оператора столкнулся с ошибкой error: second operand to the conditional operator is of type 'void', but the third operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type 'void'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
    {
        double t1, t2, T;
        int V, S, U;
        bool state;

        cout << "Enter V = ";
        cin >> V;
        cout << "Enter S = ";
        cin >> S;
        cout << "Enter U < " << V << ": ";
        cin >> U;

        t1 = S / (V + U); 
        t2 = (U >= V) 
            ? (cout << "The speed of the river is equal or greater than the speed of the boat!" << endl, exit(0) ) 
            : (t2 = S / (V - U));
        T = t1 + t2;

        cout << "T = " << T;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну так компилятор все ясно расписал. Если один операнд после `?:` имеет тип `void`, то и второй должен иметь тип `void`. У вас выражение

```
(cout << "The speed of the river is equal or greater than the speed of the boat!" << endl, exit(0) )
```

имеет тип `void` - это тип возврата функции `exit`. А выражение `(t2 = S / (V - U))` имеет тип `double`. Так перемешивать типы в `?:` не разрешается.

Раз уж вы почему-то хотите использовать именно `?:`, то можно фиктивно сделать тип второго операнда `double`

```
(cout << "..." << endl, exit(0), 0.0)
```

и ошибка пропадет.

Непонятно только, зачем вам понадобилось такое двойное присваивание в `t2`

```
t2 = (U >= V) ? ... :  (t2 = S / (V - U));
```

Уберите одно из присваиваний

```
t2 = (U >= V) ? ... :  S / (V - U);

// или

(U >= V) ? ... :  (t2 = S / (V - U));
```

При этом в последнем варианте можно будет исправить исходную ошибку и путем приведения третьего операнда к `void`

```
(U >= V) 
  ? (cout << "..." << endl, exit(0))
  : (void) (t2 = S / (V - U));
```

Answer (score 2):

Здесь вообще ни к чему тернарный оператор, обычного if будет вполне достаточно:

```
if(V < U)
{
    t2 = S / (V - U);
}
else
{
    cout << "The speed of the river is equal or greater than the speed of the boat!" << endl;
    exit(0);
}
```